# ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatсher' from 'aiogram.dispatcher'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pycharm

При попытке написания Телеграм бота вылазит ошибка:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatсher
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatсher' from 'aiogram.dispatcher'
```

Как ее можно исправить?
Библиотека установлена, PyCharm в настройках ее видит.
Unresolved reference

Сам код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatсher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import os
```

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Импорты уже другие

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher, executor
```